# Use Java polymorphism to new corresponding object (StringBuffer or StringBuilder)

Tags: java

Actually, I want to use JAVA polymorphism to design a function that it can return a StringBuffer or StringBuilder for me depends on different scenario. My error code is

```
public class Builder{
    private boolean threadSafe;
    public Builder(boolean threadSafe) {
        this.threadSafe = threadSafe;
}
    public String buildMsg(String name, int age) {
       AbstractStringBuilder asb;
       asb = threadSafe ? new StringBuffer() : new StringBuilder();
       return asb.append("name: ").append(name).append(", age: ").append(age).toString();
}
}
```

The code can not be compiled. The error message is 'java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder' is not public in 'java.lang'. Cannot be accessed from outside package.
So I try another method, use Appendable instead of AbstractStringBuilder, it still doesn't work.
Until, I write code like this:

```
public class Builder{
    private boolean threadSafe;
    public Builder(boolean threadSafe) {
        this.threadSafe = threadSafe;
}
    public String buildMsg(String name, int age) {
       if (threadSafe) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        return sb.append("name: ").append(name).append(", age: ").append(age).toString();
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        return sb.append("name: ").append(name).append(", age: ").append(age).toString();
    }
}
}
```

The code is obviously redundant. So how can I use polymorphism to fix my code.
(My English is not very well, hope you understand well)

Comment: It seems that Builder and Buffer don't implement any common interface that could be use here. You can't do it using polymorphism.

Comment: You may also consider not using StringBuffer at all...

Comment: Why aren't you using only one of them? Regarding the `threadSafe` flag, I don't see any problems with this code with multi-threading, only one thread can access the objects so no thread safety problem.

Comment: Does it *matter*? E.g., you're returning a String built using a local mechanism. (Noting that in JVMs you could just use concatenation since it defers to a builder anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for all your advises, I was wrong, Actually, in my case, whether it's StringBuffer or StringBuilder, it can not access by multi-thread, so StringBuilder here is enough. But I also want to know how to use Java polymorphism to use two classes that implement same method, but without a common interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would to advice you to just do

```
public String buildMsg(String name, int age) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb = sb
        .append("name: ")
        .append(name)
        .append(", age: ")
        .append(age);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

since there are no problems regarding multi-threading in this code. Also this is exactly what the `StringBuilder` class is for.

You should use the `StringBuffer` if multiple threads have access to the same `StringBuffer` object, but since you create the object and at the end lose the reference to it, no other thread can access the object.

---

However, to answer the question in the title.
If you have two types that both implement the method `Foo` but without a common interface, like:

```java
public class A {
    public Res Foo(Args args) { ... }
}

public class B {
    public Res Foo(Args args) { ... }
}
```

Then you will always need some casing to distinguish between both version of `Foo`.
But you can implement a Adapter or Wrapper type for both types, like:

```java
public abstract WrapperBase {
    public abstract Res Foo(Args args);

    public static WrapperBase Wrap(A a) {
        return new AWrapper(a);
    }
    public static WrapperBase Wrap(B b) {
        return new BWrapper(b);
    }
    // or
    public static WrapperBase Wrap(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof A) {
            return new AWrapper((A)obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof B) {
            return new AWrapper((B)obj);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Can not be wrapped");
        }
    }
}

class AWrapper extends WrapperBase {
    private A a;
    public AWrapper(A a) { this.a = a; }

    @override
    public Res Foo(Args args) { return a.Foo(args); }
}

class BWrapper extends WrapperBase {
    private B b;
    public BWrapper(B b) { this.b = b; }

    @override
    public Res Foo(Args args) { return b.Foo(args); }
}
```

The drawback of this is this can get out of hand if you have a larg amount of methods that you want to wrap up.

Comment: Thanks for your second advise, very useful for me. Use an adapter is a good solution for two types that both implement the method but without a common interface. As you said, I was wrong, in my case this variable can not be access by multi-thread.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer - though thread safe - is only warranted if you would allow different threads to mix things up:

Thread1:

```
sb.append("a").append("b").append("\n");
```

Thread2:

```
sb.append("c").append("d").append("\n");
```

Might result in:

```
"acb\nd\n"
```

So with StringBuffer you might need:

```
sb.append("a" + "b" + "\n");
```

which is ridiculous for obvious reasons. Also error prone when violated,
as an erroneous `sb.append(...).append(...)` might go undetected.

So it is preferable to use a thread-safe logger or your own synchronisation (around a StringWriter maybe?).

Also as these classes are final, it is really a dead-end.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, It's very useful! I was wrong, at first, I just want to use this class to build log message, The log message can be use in different scenarios, sometime they are multi-thread, sometime they are one thread, so I need to create StringBuilder or StringBuffer depends on different scenarios. That's why I want to find out their common abstract class or interface to create them depends on the parameter threadSafe I pass in. However, the StringBuilder or StringBuffer variable in my case can not be access by multi-thread.

Comment: Yes I had to think of loggers immediately. In general one should not pass mutable objects (StringBuilder/StringBuilder) that will be altered afterwards: `passToOtherThread(sb); sb.append("x");`. It would be safe with StringBuilder, but the result indeterminate.

Comment: Yes, I see, thanks for your help, it's very helpful to me!